# Clear all rules of conditionning formatting of specific excel cells in python with the library Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, formatting, openpyxl

I wanted to clear all rules of conditioning formatting of specific cells. I checked during 3 hours and found only to erase for every cell of the excel sheet but not for a specific cell:

workbook.conditional_formatting.**init**()

Is it actually possible ^^ ?

Comment: Probably, but maybe clearing a rule means adding a rule depending on how the cf rule(s) is applied.

Comment: It would help if you provided a little more context, such as the range of cells that you wish to work on.